# In PyMOL, how can I make the "resi" selection work with variables?

Tags: python, chemistry, pymol

If I want to select a residue on a protein (let's say the tenth residue), when writing a PyMOL script,  I can use the following code to assign it to a variable "pep"

```
select pep, (resi 10)
```

However, if I try to use a predefined variable in place of the numbers in the selection, no atoms are assigned to the selection.

```
    a=10
    select pep, (resi a)
```

No error is returned and no atoms are assigned to the selection. I've tried typecasting the variable as a string and as an integer, but neither one has worked. If I use the variable `a` elsewhere, such as a print statement or addition, it works perfectly fine. **Does anyone know how to make the `resi` selection work with variables?** I'm trying to use this to color amino acids differently based on some data we collected and I don't want to hard code the residues each time I analyze a new set of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is equivalent to `select pep, (resi 10)`:

```
a=10
cmd.select("pep", "resi " + str(a))
```

or

```
cmd.select("pep", "resi %i"%(a))
```